# How to add tableGrobs to dynamically generated ggplot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I've got the code to generate a set of of histograms across a set of data working, and I've got the code to generate the set of summary tables for each histogram working, but I haven't been able to combine the histograms and the tables.

Using iris data in example case:

```
#Generate list of data to be create ggplot histogram
iris.hp<-ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length)) +
   geom_histogram(binwidth =.25,origin=-0.125,
        right = TRUE,col="white", fill="steelblue4",alpha=1) + 
   labs(title = "Iris Sepal Length")+
   labs(x="Sepal Length", y="Count")
iris.hp
iris.list<-by(data = iris, INDICES = iris$Species, simplify = TRUE, 
    FUN  = function(x) {iris.hp %+% x + ggtitle(unique(x$Species))})
multi.plot<-marrangeGrob(grobs = iris.list, nrow=1,ncol=1, 
    top = quote(paste(iris$labels$title,'\nPage',g,'of',pages)))


#Generate list of data to create summary statistics table
sum.str<-aggregate(Sepal.Length~Species,iris,summary)
spec<-sum.str[,1]
spec.stats<-sum.str[,2]
sum.data<-data.frame(spec,spec.stats)
sum.table<-tableGrob(sum.data.frame)
colnames(sum.data)<-c("species","sep.len.min","sep.len.1stQ","sep.len.med",
    "sep.len.mean","sep.len.3rdQ","sep.len.max")
table.list<-by(data = sum.data, INDICES = sum.data$"species", 
     simplify = TRUE, FUN = function(x) {tableGrob(x,theme=tt3)})
multi.plot.table<-marrangeGrob(grobs = table.list,nrow=1,ncol=1, 
     top = quote(paste(iris$labels$Species,'\nPage', g, 'of',pages)))

#attempt to combine the iris.list and table.list Grobs
# updated code based on @Heroka commment 
multi.plot.test<-marrangeGrob(grobs=c(iris.list,table.list),
    nrow=1,ncol=2, top = quote(paste(occ$labels$title,'\nPage', g, 'of',pages)))
```

I can do it for a single instance using `annotation_custom`, and `grid.arrange`+`arrangeGrob` and I tried to use those with `marrangeGrob` function, but had no luck.  Just sticking both `iris.list` and `table.list` into `marrangeGrob` throws the error: 
`Error in gList(list(setosa = list(data = list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9,  : only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"`
**UPDATE**: Error was resolved when changing `marrangeGrob(grobs = list() to grobs = c()` thanks @Heroka

Any one have any pointers on how to combine the iris.list and table.list grobs and order them in such a way that the histograms match the appropriate summary statistics table? I tried to combine using `gList` but it returned an error 'only grobs' allowed in gList, and I also poked around with gTree to no avail.

Comment: You can use 'c' instead of 'list' in 'grobs=', but I think you'll need to do some reordering of your grobs because they are placed ont he pages in sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the hep @Heroka.  Changing to `grobs=c(iris.list,table.list)` did plot everything at once, but you are right it isn't adding the correct table to the correct historgram.  Any pointers on how to combine and order the two grobs to produce the correct sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally figured it out, and it seems embarrassingly simple.  In order to combine/interleave the two sets of grobs (iris histograms `iris.list` and the summary statistics tables `table.list`) into a single `glist` usable by `marrangeGrob` you can use

```
 marrangeGrob(grobs=(c(rbind(iris.list,table.list)))
```

The end result is a separate histogram plot and summary table for each type of iris: setosa, verginica, and versicolor.

**Updated working code is below.**

```
#Generate list of data to be create ggplot histogram
 iris.hp<-ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth =.25,origin=-0.125,
    right = TRUE,col="white", fill="steelblue4",alpha=1) + 
      labs(title = "Iris Sepal Length")+
      labs(x="Sepal Length", y="Count")
#Plots histogram of full iris dataset
 iris.hp
#Creates list of histogram plots for each iris using the base{by} function 
 iris.list<-by(data = iris, INDICES = iris$Species, simplify = TRUE, 
    FUN = function(x) {iris.hp %+% x + ggtitle(unique(x$Species))})
#Outputs a plot for each iris histogram
 multi.plot<-marrangeGrob(grobs = iris.list, nrow=1,ncol=1, 
     top = quote(paste(iris$labels$title,'\nPage', g, 'of',pages)))

#Generate list of data to create summary statistics table
 sum.str<-aggregate(Sepal.Length~Species,iris,summary)
 spec<-sum.str[,1]
 spec.stats<-sum.str[,2]
 sum.data<-data.frame(spec,spec.stats)
 sum.table<-tableGrob(sum.data)
 colnames(sum.data)<-c("species","sep.len.min","sep.len.1stQ","sep.len.med",
    "sep.len.mean","sep.len.3rdQ","sep.len.max")
#Creates list of summary table grobs for each iris
 table.list<-by(data = sum.data, INDICES = sum.data$"species", simplify = TRUE, 
     FUN = function(x) {tableGrob(x,theme=tt3)})
#Outputs multiple summary tables for each iris
 multi.plot.table<-marrangeGrob(grobs = table.list,nrow=1,ncol=1, 
     top = quote(paste(iris$labels$Species,'\nPage', g, 'of',pages)))


#Combined histogram and summary table across multiple plots
 multi.plots<-marrangeGrob(grobs=(c(rbind(iris.list,table.list))),nrow=2, ncol=1, 
     top = quote(paste(occ$labels$title,'\nPage', g, 'of',pages)))
```